# drill down taxonomy node count using views

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I don't know if I'm the only one having this issue but my problem seems to be common. I just could not find the solution here and Google.

My site have the taxonomy menu:
Classifieds
  Electronics
  Autos
Jobs
  Accounting
  Information Technology
I just want to show a summary for every term that has children on it. E.g., When you click on Classifieds it should show like this:
 
Electronics(160)
Autos(310)
And when you click on Autos(310) it should show for example:
Aston Martin(200)
Toyota(110)
And then drill down to the last child item with node count. (e.g. DB9 Coupe (xx) etc..) 
When I use the views default summary display and you clicked on 'classifieds' it will show:
Free Stuffs(xx)
DB9 Coupe(xx) <-- this should should first as 'Autos' and not show the last child in the hierarchy!

Basically, it's just a page with summary counts of terms being used in nodes and count them by level in the taxonomy hierarchy. So, from clicking a parent term, the first child terms will only show with node counts, then when clicking on one child only the children of this child will show with node counts etc..

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI. For those who have the same issue above. I managed to do this in Drupal 7 and it's called facet search primarily using Apache Solr or without Apache Solr [here](http://envisioninteractive.com/drupal/drupal-7-views-with-faceted-filters-without-apachesolr/)

Comment: Hi,I have the same issue,how did you manage it?Could you tell the configuration of facets?thanks